# two ways communication in web services

Tags: web-services, websocket, jms, mom

How can I have two ways communication with WS. Two ways means a client could be a server and a server could be a client. As far as I understand the problem related to the client-server model in HTTP which is used by WS. What is the best practice for this scenario when a server wants send an event to multiple clients without being polled. ?
As far as I know there are some solutions but I do not know which one is best
1) server-push techniques (websockets)
2) SOAP over JMS  (this sounds great)
3) WS-eventing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a webservice is - as the name says - to serve. It responds to requests, but it never sends requests on its own (but an application accessed through a webservice interface could send requests to other webservices to fulfill a request sent to it).

When a component of a [service-oriented architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) is supposed to receive events from another component, it means that the receiving component has to act as a server and expose an own web services interface so that the component where the event occured can call it.